# Which government agencies oversee development of new AI?

Tags: control-problem, singularity, ai-security

Nick Bostrom talks in his book [Superintelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintelligence:_Paths,_Dangers,_Strategies) about the many dangers of AI. He considers it necessary that strong security mechanisms are put in place to ensure that a machine, once it gains general intelligence far beyond human capabilities, does not destroy humanity (most likely by accident). He describes this as a very delicate process that most likely will go wrong.

Considering that new technologies often neglect the necessary precautions and  that this is highly relevant to national security, I wonder if there are already government agencies overseeing big technology companies like Deepmind. We are currently far away from an intelligence explosion or a technological singularity, but I would assume that governments want to have a foot in the door as soon as they realize and understand the dangers.

So my question is, what government agencies currently investigate and maybe even control AI development? The answer can be general or for a specific country if there is a big difference between countries.

Answer (score 2):

May not be quite what you’re looking for, but nonetheless helpful, I hope. The White House a year ago commissioned a [report on AI](https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/sites/default/files/whitehouse_files/microsites/ostp/NSTC/preparing_for_the_future_of_ai.pdf) that touches briefly on policy issues.

Comment: Thx for pointing to the report. Yes, not exactly was I was looking for, but an interesting read nevertheless. Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

Although I (partly) agree with Nick Bostroms view that Artificial Intelligence could in some ways be dangerous. We do not need new government bodies to control or regulate AI development.

We already have sufficient cyber laws that protect us against computer crimes such as cyber terrorism, cyber bulling, creating malware, identity theft, DOSS, unauthorized access e.t.c.  It is the duty of local law enforcement agencies and the FBI to prevent and investigate cybercrimes such as those listed above. Whether AI was used to perpetrate the crime is legally immaterial.

Although AI is a 'new' technology. We already have a rigorous criminal justice system within our governance structures that are well capable of handling any eventualities that may arise from AI or any other technological breakthroughs without being overwhelmed.

For example if an AI causes a car accident the manufacturer of the car can simply be charged for Product Liability for Negligence. If an AI is defective or dangerous. We already have product liability and consumer protection laws and the relevant government agencies to implement them.

If an AI uses its intelligence to maneuver within the law to its own advantage. This by definition is not a crime, big corporations do this all the time to minimize their taxes. However if necessary, the legislature can sit and pass a law criminalizing/banning this new activity.

A sovereign government already has enough powers and the neccessary instruments to excercise that power. Creation of a new government agency will lead to the unneccessary duplication of responsibilities.

The best approach is simply for the relevant government agencies to adapt by playing a proactive role and modernizing their service delivery so that it is in sync with current developments within society.This is what everyone has to do.
In reality we do not need additional agencies. I would find agencies for example Federal Ai Agency
or Federal Blockchain Commission to be baffling and unproductive.